# Ionic 2 How to store Push notification in Notification board

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I have an app that can receive several notifications at the same time.
I'm able to receive all of them (by setting style as inbox) but the issue is that when the user click on one notification, the app is opened and ALL the notification disappears... Is there a way that the device can keep the OTHER notifications in the notification list until the user click each of them?
I saw this working in other apps, but I'm trying to do it with Ionic2.

Thanks!

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ check its instance members like `clearAll()`,`clear(Id)`,`get(notificationId)` ..etc

Comment: I pull all the information from the server where my database keeps track of read and unread notifications. I don't store anything on device

Comment: @edison I'm trying to do the opposite... I don't want the unread notification to dissapear from the notification center if the user didin't click on them... just the one that was read can be removed. Is that possible?